# Differential of Quantum mean value or expectation value

Tags: quantum-mechanics

How to take differential of Quantum mean value over hermitian operator (mean or expectation value)?
$$d\langle \hat A\rangle$$
remark:
or time evolution of mean value over operator
$$\frac {d\langle \hat A\rangle}{dt}$$

> what is the problem here?
>   ok let me talk a little more special in three steps.
>   1. In classical phyaics differential of momentum is:
>   $$dp=dmv=mdv$$
>   2. In relativistic physics differential of a momentum is:
>   $$dp=dmv=mdv + vdm$$
>   3. how about differential of relativistic quantum mean value over momentum operator?
>   $$d\langle \hat P\rangle=?$$

I register ,here is my account:
[mare](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/16861/mare)

but i dont have access to my questions!.

Comment: What's the problem here? A differential of anything is always the same thing - applied to different quantities. I don't quite understand how it's possible to know what "differential of something" means so that "differential of the mean value" would still need a clarification.

Comment: Dear mare, I saw your update. The Leibniz rule $d(xy)=dx\cdot y+x\cdot dy$ still holds even if $x,y$ are mean values or operators or anything of the sort. Also, $d\langle A\rangle = \langle dA\rangle$ and similar identities. For $d\langle\hat P\rangle$  one just adds hats to all the quantities in the unhatted identity. Does it answer your questions?

Comment: If you want your accounts merged, please fill both profile pages with a "Please merge with <link to profile>", where <link to profile> links to the other profile.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you missed another type of force:

In Lagrangian Mechanics there is a scalar potential field V in
which the gradient of  V is the force:
$$F=-\nabla V$$

and this is exactly what we dealing with in QM.

$$\frac {d \langle \hat P\rangle}{dt}=\langle \hat F\rangle=\langle -\nabla V\rangle$$

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you only work in the 'wavefunction' approximation then $\langle \hat A \rangle = \langle \Psi | \hat A | \Psi \rangle$

The differential or time derivative follow in the usual way. For instance

$$\frac {d \langle \hat A \rangle}{dt}
=
\frac {d \langle \Psi |}{dt} \hat A | \Psi \rangle
+
\langle \Psi | \frac{\partial \hat{A}}{\partial t} | \Psi \rangle
+
\langle \Psi | \hat A \frac {d | \Psi \rangle}{dt}$$

Using the Schrodinger equation for the 'wavefunction' and working a bit one finally arrives to

$$\frac {d \langle \hat A \rangle}{dt}
=
\frac{1}{i\hbar} \langle [\hat{A},\hat{H}] \rangle
+
\left\langle \frac{\partial \hat{A}}{\partial t} \right\rangle$$

A result known as Eherenfest theorem. The differential can be obtained by multiplying everything by $dt$. The momentum operator $\hat{P}$ does not depend explicitly on time and the last term vanishes

$$\frac {d \langle \hat P \rangle}{dt}
=
\frac{1}{i\hbar} \langle [\hat{P},\hat{H}] \rangle$$